# Validating Social Security Numbers through Regular Expressions

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex, textbox

I want to do like this -

[image]

I want to do when I put cursor in the text box it should be empty and how I can show 000-00-0000 format while page load.

I have tried this-

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator2" runat="server" 
   ControlToValidate="TextBox7" ErrorMessage="Social Security No. is wrong." 
   ValidationExpression="^\d{3}-\d{2}-\d{4}$">
</asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

but its not showing 000-00-0000 when I load the page and when I put cursor in the text box it should disappear the 000-00-0000.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried just setting the value of TextBox7 to 000-00-0000 in your aspx page?

Comment: Please check http://aspsnippets.com/Articles/Watermark-TextBox-using-JavaScript.aspx

Comment: stribizhev , The Article is very helpful, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for a `placeholder`? Given an HTML input as

```
<input type="text" placeholder="000-00-0000" />
```

you will see an input box with ghosted letters `000-00-0000` which disappear and reappear when the user focuses or blurs the element. To do this in Asp.net, you might try

```
<asp:textbox placeholder="000-00-0000" runat="server" />
```

Additionally, if a user does not enter the `-` characters, could the `ValidationExpression` be modified to be optional?

```
ValidationExpression="^\d{3}-?\d{2}-?\d{4}$"
```

Then either `000000000` and `000-00-0000` would be accepted, which you could deal with server-side when the form is submitted.

Comment: Thanks ! The answer is very helpful for my requirement.